ERR_SSL_WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER when fetching data from Nextjs API
I am trying to fetch some data from my NextJS api however when i do, i get this SSL error, even when i fetch using fetch~("/api/categopries") it says invalid url, but my api is in the same directory.
export default async function SectionContent() {
  const getData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("https://localhost:3000/api/categories");

    if (!res.ok) {
      console.log("Failed to fetch data");
    }

    return res.json();
  };

  const categories: Category[] = await getData();

  return (
    <div className="p-10 space-y-14 w-full h-full">
      <div className="flex gap-x-3">
        <span className="text-3xl"></span>
        <span className="font-extrabold text-3xl">Todo list</span>
      </div>
      <CreateTodoDialog />
      <TodoSection />
    </div>
  );
}

This is my API
export async function GET(req: Request) {
  const session = await getServerSession();

  if (!session?.user) {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "Invalid session" }, { status: 400 });
  }

  const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
    where: {
      email: session.user.email || "",
    },
  });

  if (!user) {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "User not found" }, { status: 400 });
  }

  const categories = await prisma.category.findMany({
    where: {
      authorId: user.id,
    },
    include: {
      todos: true,
    },
  });

  return NextResponse.json(categories, { status: 201 });
}


i tried doing npm update but it did not resolve the issue.

Are you sure you're running the web server in secure mode? It defaults to insecure (or http)

You are right! Thank you i did not see that extra s, thought it was https

I had a similar problem having Next.js proxied in nginx on a bridge network.
Changed const loginUrl = ${request.nextUrl.origin}/api/login; to this: const loginUrl = ${process.env.CONTAINER_HOST}/api/login; in my middleware (CONTAINER_HOST=http://nextjs:3000)
